# Compound normal distribution with mean = normal and variance = exponential

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I have X,Y ~ i.i.d. Normal(M, S), where in turn M ~ N(2,1) and S ~ exponential(1).

I have to evaluate COV(X,Y) and E(X^2 Y^2).

For COV(X,Y), I need E(X) = M, E(Y) = M.  I also need E(XY), which I calculated using the usual method:

E(XY) = double integral (-inf to inf) x*y * (pdf of X) (pdf of Y) dx dy

Here PDF of X and PDF of Y turn out to be functions of M and S, and the double integral evaluated by parts leads me to an answer which gives (inf - (-inf)), which doesn't make sense.

I think I should probably use some other method to work on distributions which have random variables as parameters.  I checked the textbook Intro to Probability models by Sheldon Ross but couldn't find anything on compound random variables.

I'll be grateful for any guidance on how to proceed here... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the hierarchical model is:

$$M \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = 2, \sigma = 1), \\ 
S \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(1), \\
X \mid M, S \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = M, \sigma = S), \\
Y \mid M, S \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = M, \sigma = S).$$

Note that I am assuming that $S$ is the conditional standard deviation of $X$, rather than the variance.  Then we have
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[X] &= \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[X \mid M, S]] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[M] \\
&= 2,
\end{align}$$
and similarly for $Y$.  And

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}[X] &= \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[X \mid M, S]] + \operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[X \mid M, S]] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[S^2] + \operatorname{Var}[M] \\
&= \operatorname{Var}[S] + \operatorname{E}[S]^2 + \operatorname{Var}[M] \\
&= 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 = 3.
\end{align}$$

The *unconditional* expectation of $XY$ is

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[XY] &= \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[XY \mid M, S]] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[M^2] \\
&= \operatorname{Var}[M] + \operatorname{E}[M]^2 \\
&= 1^2 + 2^2 = 5.
\end{align}$$

From this, it is easy to compute the covariance.  I leave the calculation of $\operatorname{E}[X^2 Y^2]$ as an exercise.  The relevant formulas we have used here are the laws of total expectation and total variance.

Comment: Hello heropup, Thank you for the illustration!  I have been working out the conditional expectations and conditional variances here.  I am stuck at the point where we have to find E(XY).  I can see that the law of iterated expectations is being used here.  But I don't understand why E(XY | M, S) = M^2.

Comment: Hello heropup, Thank you for the illustration!  I have been working out the conditional expectations and conditional variances here. I am stuck at the point where we have to find E(XY).  I can see that the law of iterated expectations is being used here.  But I don't understand why E(XY | M, S) = M^2.  We have X | M, S & Y | M, S : both these conditional distributions are normal.  Given this, I am confused about how to get the distribution of XY | M, S.  The sum of 2 iid normal random variables is normal, but here we have the product of X & Y... I'm stuck here and will be grateful for advice.

Comment: The unconditional distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are dependent (because realizations of an $(X,Y)$ pair are generated with the same $M$ and $S$, but their conditional distributions are *independent* IID normal, each with mean $M$.  Therefore, $\operatorname{E}[XY \mid M, S] = \operatorname{E}[X \mid M, S]\operatorname{E}[Y \mid M, S] = M^2$.

Comment: Think of the model as an algorithm:  (1) Generate one $M \sim \operatorname{Normal}(2,1)$.  (2) Generate one $S \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(1)$.  (3) Then use these as the mean and SD parameters to generate *two* (conditionally) independent normal variables, $X$ and $Y$.  Conditioned on knowing what $M$ and $S$ were, $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  But if you draw a scatter plot of many $(X,Y)$ ordered pairs, you will find the points are positively correlated, because each pair came from a normal distribution with the same mean $M$.

Comment: The algorithm example makes this easier to understand.  I get that the conditional distributions of X and Y, given M and S are independent, which seems to be key here. Thank you once again.